# setting muliple columns with same value , in a factory girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

```
Factory.define(:player) do |u|
    u.association(:owner), :factory => :user
    u.association(:updater), :factory => user
end
```

Can i rewrite the above definition such that , I can initialize the values of the owner and updater to be the same, without passing them in explicitly when i call create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Factory.define(:player) do |uu|
  uu.association(:owner), :factory => :user
  uu.association(:updater), { |player| player.owner }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

When defining associations, I often find it easier to use one of the `after_create` or `after_build` hooks:

```
Factory.define(:player) do |u|

  after_build do |player|
    user = FactoryGirl.create :user
    player.owner = user
    player.creator = user
  end

end
```

I also usually try to set up my factories so they'll work whether I'm building (instantiating) or creating (instantiating and saving), but ActiveRecord is a bit finicky about how you set up the associations when you're just building, so I used create in this example.